# How To render HTML Table with two Json data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have to render a HTML table from two JSON Data as per user requirement i have to get data from two queries independently so i am getting two json data

almost 85% work is done just facing issue to remder some values from data2

**Snippet**

```js
var data = [{
    "outlet": "S0001",
    "brandcode": "B0002",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "grn": 5810
  },
  {
    "outlet": "S0001",
    "brandcode": "B0003",
    "brandname": "Finished Goods",
    "grn": 5895
  },
  {
    "outlet": "S0001",
    "brandcode": "B0004",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "grn": 162810
  },
  {
    "outlet": "S0001",
    "brandcode": "B0005",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "grn": 281591
  },
  {
    "outlet": "S0001",
    "brandcode": "B0006",
    "brandname": "North Indian FG",
    "grn": 3824
  },
  {
    "outlet": "S0002",
    "brandcode": "B0002",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "grn": 7848
  },
  {
    "outlet": "S0002",
    "brandcode": "B0003",
    "brandname": "Finished Goods",
    "grn": 6970
  },
  {
    "outlet": "S0002",
    "brandcode": "B0004",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "grn": 136450
  },
  {
    "outlet": "S0002",
    "brandcode": "B0005",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "grn": 242644
  },
  {
    "outlet": "S0002",
    "brandcode": "B0006",
    "brandname": "North Indian FG",
    "grn": 8618
  }
]
var data2 = [{
    "netAmount": 587714 // i am trying to populate this on netAmount of S0001
    "outlet": "S0001"
  },
  {
    "netAmount": 115257,
    "outlet": "S0002" // i am trying to populate this on netAmount of S0002  and total of S0001+S0002=individual sales Total
  }

]


let formatData = function(data) {
  let brandcodes = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (brandcodes.indexOf(element.brandcode) == -1) {
      brandcodes.push(element.brandcode);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    brandcodes: brandcodes,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};
var totalSalesPercentage = ''; //this one is to display percentage for Total column
var olWiseSalesPercentage = ''; // tghis one is to show percentage for outlet columns
let renderTable = function(data) {
  brandcodes = data.brandcodes;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("BillCountTable");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0; //this is grand total for total column
  let grandNetAmount = 0; //this is the one to populate all total of netamount
  let outletWiseTotal = {}; //this one is outlet wise total object
  let outletWiseNetamount = {}; //and this one to populate outlet wise netamount
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 2;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 2;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0; //this one is to store olwise total whatr i am looking for to calculate percentage
    // outletWiseNetamount[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.grn);
        //      outletWiseNetamount[element] += parseInt(el.netAmount);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
    // grandNetAmount += outletWiseNetamount[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Sales";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Grn Entery";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);
  let el1 = 0;
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);
    if (element.outlet == element) {
      el1 = element.netAmount;
      //      outletWiseNetamount[element] += parseInt(el.netAmount);
      console.log(el1)
    }
    console.log(el1)
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = "netAmount"; //this one is net amount outlet wise which i am getting in data2
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "individual sales Total"; //this is also net amount but it is the sum of ll net amount outlet wise
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  brandcodes.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalBCount = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      let bc = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.brandcode == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.grn);
          totalBCount += parseInt(d.billcount);
          el = d.grn;
          bc = d.billcount;
        }
      });

      olWiseSalesPercentage = (el / outletWiseTotal[outlet]) * 100 // calculating percentage for Total column
      console.log("value :-" + olWiseSalesPercentage)

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
      //console.log("ol wise data -:" +el)
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = olWiseSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%";
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    totalSalesPercentage = (total / grandTotal) * 100 // calculating percentage for Total column

    const totalSalesPercentageFix = totalSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%"
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalSalesPercentageFix;
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    tbody.appendChild(row);

  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">
  <table id=BillCountTable>
  </table>
</div>
```

At the place of `netAmount` i want to put netAmount of data2 json and then calculate there sum and render it to `indiuvidual sales Total =netamount of S0001+netamount of S0002`

My code is bit of lengthy that's why i have commented all the lines to know you all what i am doing where

[image: this the output i am trying to get]

anyone out here please help

Comment: There's a lot of code there. What are the names of the two javascript variables you are trying to add together, and what is the name of the variable in which you want to store the result?

Comment: @Cat  `let grandNetAmount = 0;` this is the total net amount which will be put at the place of `individual sales Total` and  `let netAmount=0` to populate outlet wise total and also i am commented the line where i have to put these values in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the pass the data2 array inside render table function then filter with outlets respected

```
td.innerHTML =data2.filter(a=> a.outlet == element)[0]['netAmount']
```

For individual sales total

```
td.innerHTML = data2.reduce((a,b)=> (a = a+b.netAmount,a),0);
```

```js
var data = [{ "outlet": "S0001", "brandcode": "B0002", "brandname": "Bakery FG", "grn": 5810 }, { "outlet": "S0001", "brandcode": "B0003", "brandname": "Finished Goods", "grn": 5895 }, { "outlet": "S0001", "brandcode": "B0004", "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG", "grn": 162810 }, { "outlet": "S0001", "brandcode": "B0005", "brandname": "Ice Cream FG", "grn": 281591 }, { "outlet": "S0001", "brandcode": "B0006", "brandname": "North Indian FG", "grn": 3824 }, { "outlet": "S0002", "brandcode": "B0002", "brandname": "Bakery FG", "grn": 7848 }, { "outlet": "S0002", "brandcode": "B0003", "brandname": "Finished Goods", "grn": 6970 }, { "outlet": "S0002", "brandcode": "B0004", "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG", "grn": 136450 }, { "outlet": "S0002", "brandcode": "B0005", "brandname": "Ice Cream FG", "grn": 242644 }, { "outlet": "S0002", "brandcode": "B0006", "brandname": "North Indian FG", "grn": 8618 } ];
var data2 = [{ "netAmount": 587714, "outlet": "S0001" }, { "netAmount": 115257, "outlet": "S0002" }
]

let formatData = function(data) {
  let brandcodes = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (brandcodes.indexOf(element.brandcode) == -1) {
      brandcodes.push(element.brandcode);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    brandcodes: brandcodes,
    outlets: outlets,
  };
};
var totalSalesPercentage = ''; //this one is to display percentage for Total column
var olWiseSalesPercentage = ''; // tghis one is to show percentage for outlet columns
let renderTable = function(data, data2) {
  brandcodes = data.brandcodes;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("BillCountTable");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0; //this is grand total for total column
  let grandNetAmount = 0; //this is the one to populate all total of netamount
  let outletWiseTotal = {}; //this one is outlet wise total object
  let outletWiseNetamount = {}; //and this one to populate outlet wise netamount
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 2;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 2;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0; //this one is to store olwise total whatr i am looking for to calculate percentage
    // outletWiseNetamount[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.grn);
        //      outletWiseNetamount[element] += parseInt(el.netAmount);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
    // grandNetAmount += outletWiseNetamount[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Sales";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Grn Entery";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);
  let el1 = 0;
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element)
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);
    if (element.outlet == element) {
      el1 = element.netAmount;
      //      outletWiseNetamount[element] += parseInt(el.netAmount);
    }
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = data2.filter(a => a.outlet == element)[0]['netAmount']; //this one is net amount outlet wise which i am getting in data2
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = data2.reduce((a, b) => (a = a + b.netAmount, a), 0); //this is also net amount but it is the sum of ll net amount outlet wise
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  brandcodes.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalBCount = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      let bc = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.brandcode == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.grn);
          totalBCount += parseInt(d.billcount);
          el = d.grn;
          bc = d.billcount;
        }
      });

      olWiseSalesPercentage = (el / outletWiseTotal[outlet]) * 100 // calculating percentage for Total column


      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
      //console.log("ol wise data -:" +el)
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = olWiseSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%";
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    totalSalesPercentage = (total / grandTotal) * 100 // calculating percentage for Total column

    const totalSalesPercentageFix = totalSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%"
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalSalesPercentageFix;
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    tbody.appendChild(row);

  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData, data2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">
  <table id=BillCountTable>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes @dheeraj kumar tell me

Comment: Sorry bro.. i m in wrk. please ask your doubt..i will explain

Comment: hey i got the answer by my self :)

Comment: Nice. post the answer on that question.its helpfull for future visitor

Comment: yup just stuck with one issue once done with that will post for sure

Comment: hey i am sorry that i am disturbing you,but i have a problem How to abort query when page is refreshed or back button clicked,please check once you get some time

Comment: @dheerajkumar .now free.tell me

Comment: can you please check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162770/how-to-kill-query-process-when-page-is-refreshed-or-back-button-clicked

Answer (score -1):

The above code is creating the dom elements via JS. Instead, we can combine the two different responses based on the requirement and use BootstrapTable plugin or could use a templating strategy like handlebars, which would make the code clean.

Comment: This question allows a much better answer, with a clear snippet of how things should work

Comment: i have already done so much things which is clearly understandable